# What does init in Objective-C actually do?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

```
+ (id)alloc;
```

and

```
- (id)init;
```

are methods from NSObject.h

The alloc does

```
+ (id)alloc {
    return _objc_rootAlloc(self);
}


id
_objc_rootAlloc(Class cls)
{
#if 0  &&  __OBJC2__
    // Skip over the +allocWithZone: call if the class doesn't override it.
    // fixme not - this breaks ObjectAlloc
    if (! ((class_t *)cls)->isa->hasCustomAWZ()) {
        return class_createInstance(cls, 0);
    }
#endif
    return [cls allocWithZone: nil];
}
```

It does memory allocation, and return a class Instance.

But when I came to the init method, this is the implementation

```
- (id)init {
    return _objc_rootInit(self);
}

id
_objc_rootInit(id obj)
{
    // In practice, it will be hard to rely on this function.
    // Many classes do not properly chain -init calls.
    return obj;
}
```

It only return self object  (NSObject) without doing any initialization.

The documentation also says the same thing.

"The init method defined in the NSObject class does no initialization; it simply returns self."

If that is the case, alloc method alone is sufficient.
Init method is only required for overridding.

Any explanation here?

---

This is the implementation source NSObject.mm

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/NSObject.mm

Comment: What is your question? It seems like you've answered it yourself and with the code you've found.

Comment: Pay no attention to the man behind the curtain. Always say some form of `init` at the same moment you say `alloc`.

Comment: The purpose of `init` method is overriding. Documentation also says "Do not override alloc to include initialization code. Instead, implement class-specific versions of init... methods.".

Comment: Seems the init method exist for only overriding purpose. It really does nothing.

Comment: @JesseRusak Thanks for your response. I just found it strange. because the init method really does nothing. It exists only for overriding purpose.

Comment: But it's good practice to call `[[class alloc] init]`, Apple requires it (mentioned in documentation) and you don't know if `init` method will does nothing in the future. Now it does nothing (in `NSObject` class). In other classes it may does something more. Eg. `NSArray` class is a class cluster, there may be something more in the `init` method. You should definitely use `alloc` with `init`.

Comment: I asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662810/if-i-do-nothing-in-init-is-it-the-same-as-just-calling-myclass-alloc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`alloc` is to do with memory allocation while `init` (or `initX` etc., the `init` family) is to do with configuring that allocated memory as needed when an object is created - whether any particular class, now or in the future following some revision, needs to do any work in `init` is dependent on the semantics of that class. However as you don't know for any arbitrary class whether it's `init` needs to do any work you must call it, and as any arbitrary class does not know whether its superclass needs to do any initialisation to must call its superclasses `init` within its own `init`. For this chain to work `NSObject` must have an `init`, it so happens that it (currently, who knows in the future) does no work. `NSObject`'s `init` is the end of the chain and the only one that does not need to call another `init`.

Confusion arises for some as many languages combine the two operations, allocation and initialisation, into one indivisible operation, e.g. `new` in Java. Indeed Cocoa has a `new` as well which is defined as `alloc` followed by `init`.

And Apple should really have written:

> The init method defined in the NSObject class *currently* does no initialization; it simply returns self.

or simply said nothing.

HTH

Comment: I agree.
init method does nothing except return the self class.
But maybe in future, Apple will implement something to it.
And who knows, another programmer overrided the init method. 
For safety purpose I will always use init method.

Comment: Note that `alloc` also zeroes the whole memory and sets up `isa`, so there is some memory initialization actually involved in `alloc`.

Answer (score 0):

CRD explained it pretty well.

I will state it more strongly, however.

The way you create a new object in Objective C is to use alloc/init.

You should always initialize every object, and custom init methods should always call `[super init]`. Consider failure to call init on ALL objects an error, and also consider calling `[super init]` in your custom init methods an error.